# Need to Forecast using time series data

Tags: forecasting

How do I forecast the following data of 36 months?
days
1279
1519
2031
1491
1538
1876
1329
1134
2040
1215
1757
2452
1138
1592
2253
1628
1576
2015
1302
1554
1912
1607
1545
2527
1603
1889
2175
1887
1755
2089
1526
1547
2164
1681
1513
2298

These data are collected for a period of 36 months. Months are divided into weeks for a given quarter in 4,4,5 weeks. These are the days delivered as Consulting days for a given period. I want to forecast how many days will I deliver in next 12 months (month-wise data)

Comment: Stats questions aren't ever as simple as math questions: there are too many good answers available depending on the context.  To narrow it down, please tell us what these data mean, how they were collected, and what the purpose of forecasting might be.

Comment: @Stephan I appreciate your position, but I still cannot agree that this question is sufficiently narrow.  Unless you have prepared a textbook on time series analysis for your response, it's hard to see how you could adequately address this in its present form.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I'm happy to vote to reopen this so you can answer it, but I think your answer should have a perfunctory first paragraph along the lines of, 'you could forecast using <method>, if you prioritize <something>, or <method>, if you prefer <this pro> to <this con>, etc. There are very many possibilities here. I will just discuss a common approach that may or may not be ideal for your situation.' Or something like that to address the breadth aspect.

Answer (score 3):

Read your data and transform it into a `ts` object:

```
foo <- scan()
1279 1519 2031 1491 1538 1876 1329 1134 2040 1215 1757 2452 1138 1592 2253 1628 1576 2015 1302 1554 1912 1607 1545 2527 1603 1889 2175 1887 1755 2089 1526 1547 2164 1681 1513 2298

foo.ts <- ts(foo,frequency=12)
```

Look at a seasonplot:

```
library(forecast)
seasonplot(foo.ts)
```

[image: seasonplot]

This shows recurring patterns, i.e., seasonality. The pattern repeats every three months, according to your 4, 4, 5 weeks accounting pattern. As such, it might make sense to work not with yearly seasonality (`frequency=12`), but with a three-month seasonality (`frequency=3`). For now, we will stay with the yearly seasonality, which is usually more natural.

Fit an ETS model, i.e., a state space model including Error, Trend and Seasonality:

```
model <- ets(foo.ts)
model
```

We see that `ets()` fits a model with additive error, no trend and additive seasonality. Here is a forecast from this model:

```
plot(forecast(model,h=12))
```

[image: forecast]

Forecasting is a vast field, and this is just one possible (very) first analysis. For more information, look at [this free online open source textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp).

Comment: +1 Nice job balancing generality with focus on the data.  Based on a recent experience, I am paying attention to the 4,4,5 week definition of a "month," because I have found that can have a profound effect on a time series analysis.  Would you have a recommendation for how to deal with that?  The obvious method is to normalize the data into a rate per unit time (like rate per week): but would that have any hidden pitfalls, or could it be improved upon easily?

Comment: @whuber: normalization is one possibilty. Or simply regressing the outcome on the number of weeks, then doing a time series analysis on residuals. However, often a quarterly pattern is actually not so much due to the 4-4-5 binning, but more to salespeople rushing to make their quota before the end of the quarter, so the last days show increased activity - and that this just coincides with the 5-week-"month" is a red herring. So I'd always recommend going down to a lower granularity, e.g., daily, and looking at patterns there.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas.  The "rushing to make their quota" is also a familiar phenomenon. When it's strong enough, it induces an appreciable negative correlation between the period that ends a quarter and the period that begins the next quarter.  Are you aware of any formulations that explicitly take that into account for modeling and forecasting?

Comment: No, not in a formalized way. Much of this is already covered by standard seasonality, of course. It's not far-fetched to add dummies. And usually this quarter end effect applies to bookings or contract signings, not to deliveries of products and services. Both contracts and deliveries are forecasted, but I'm more involved with the second kind.